# How to find the position clicked from onOptionsItemSelected

Tags: android

I have a Gallery view, In this view I set up an options menu

```
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    menu.add(0, EMAIL_MENU_ID, 0, "Email");
    menu.add(0, SHARE_MENU_ID, 0, "Share");
    menu.add(0, RATE_MENU_ID, 0, "Rate");
    menu.add(0, BUY_MENU_ID, 0, "Buy");

    return true;
}
```

I have the following method to get the option item selected.

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


    switch (item.getItemId()) {
     case EMAIL_MENU_ID:
         sendMail(index);
     case SHARE_MENU_ID:
         postToWeb(index);
     case RATE_MENU_ID:
         postRating(index);
     case BUY_MENU_ID:
         buy(index);
     }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

How could i find the item of the Gallery view that's currently in focus?

Comment: May be this blog has the answer you are looking. http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/05/gallery-view-android-developer-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

Very good tutorial.  In my scenario the user has pressed the Menu button and I would like to present the user with some options to take on the image that is currently in focus. At this point the user has not clicked on the image so I don't have the position that you would normally get when a user selects an item. I've thought about using a context menu instead but was hoping to use an options menu.